# Logistic Regression as a Semi-Supervised Classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am experimenting with text classification for multiple classes in Python. I am using the SciKit-Learn package which has most of the classifiers in-built. I had experimented with different classifiers and Logistic Regression seems to give the best result (accuracy >74%)at the moment. Now as a next step I want to test if I can use Logistic regression as a semi-supervised classifier. Reason being, I tried the label-propagation classifier in built in Scikit-Learn and it doesn't do well in terms of accuracy (<57%) for the five classes I have. Now I wanted to check if any one has used logistic regression classifier as a semi-supervised classifier or not? Also is there a way to tweak the Scikit Learn package to achieve the above. Any directions on how to go about the above would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use a semi-supervised method? Do you not have enough labeled ground truth?

Comment: No, I don't have much labelled data. In fact only 20% of the data is labelled. Thus, I wanted to try something that gives me the advantage of both supervised as well as semi-supervised.

Comment: A simple approach is self-training, where you retrain your classifier on previous predictions. That is really simple to implement based of the LogisticRegression classifier you have. You could also try a transductive SVM, which is however not implemented in scikit-learn.